# Unexpected Error while saving Animation of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I want to Animate a 3D Polar Plot and export it, because my Computer has not enough CPU Power for displaying it with `plt.show()` (If you have a good solution how to calculate it before showing, I would appreciate it, too)
Unfortunatly the export does not work and I do not know why. To my mind this should work.
Is it possible that my Python IDE(PyCharm)  oder my Python Version(2.7) is responsible?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython import display

psi_vec = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1)
radius = np.arange(0,1,0.05)
Z_ones = np.ones(63)

def animate(time):
    X = np.zeros((np.size(psi_vec), np.size(radius)))
    Y = np.zeros((np.size(psi_vec), np.size(radius)))
    Z = np.zeros((np.size(psi_vec), np.size(radius)))

    for i in range(np.size(radius)):
        X[:,i] = np.cos(psi_vec) * radius[i]
        Y[:,i] = np.sin(psi_vec) * radius[i]
        Z[:,i] = np.sin(time) * i * Z_ones
        line = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,color= 'b')
    return line

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 15, interval = 500)
video = anim.to_html5_video()
html = display(video)
display.display(html)
```

The Error Message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexander/Dokumente/PetersHe (vectors)/animation.py", line 48, in <module>
    video = anim.to_html5_video()
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1353, in to_html5_video
    self.save(f.name, writer=writer)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1200, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 241, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 367, in finish
    self.cleanup()
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 405, in cleanup
    out, err = self._proc.communicate()
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 748, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1557, in _communicate
    orig_timeout)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1613, in _communicate_with_poll
    register_and_append(self.stdout, select_POLLIN_POLLPRI)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda2/envs/PyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1592, in register_and_append
    poller.register(file_obj.fileno(), eventmask)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank You!

Comment: Minimum Python version supported by current matplotlib is Python 3.6, so that may be a problem. Is there an error message?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have to use Python 2.7. The error message is trivial I think : 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file'

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Ok, like that? I found it is a litlle bit to long. But thanks for your comment, I'll try to improve my style.

Comment: it shows problem in line `ani.save(fn+'.mp4',writer='ffmpeg',fps=fps)` which I don't see in your code.

Comment: when I run your code (in JUpyter) then I get error in `html = display(video)` because it should be `display.display(video)` .  BTW: I think you have wrong indentation and `line = ...` should be outside/after `for`-loop. Now you draw almost the same surface inside loop but finally you will see only last surface - so there is no need to draw all of them but only last one. And this way it should run faster.

Comment: @furas Yes I ve runned the wrong file sorry,.